How can I get a custom action to NOT show up on the toolbar?
I have a custom action to launch a custom report that's coded as follows:
    public PXAction<PMProject> projectRegDet;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Project Register Detailed")]
    [PXButton(DisplayOnMainToolbar = false, CommitChanges = true, Category = "Reports")]
    protected virtual void ProjectRegDet()
    {
        PMProject proj = Base.Project.Current;

        if (proj.ContractCD != null)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters["ProjectID"] = proj.ContractCD;

            throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, "LFS99002", null);
        }
    }

It works fine, but I've added it to the 'Reports' section of the actions menu (in the ellipse actions) - and I can't get it to NOT show up on the toolbar.  Everything I've tried makes no difference.  The code you see is the last thing I tried - but before that I tried adding it to the Actions on the customization project, setting visible = false, adding a callback command in the ASPX and setting that visibility to false... nothing I do seems to make any difference.  It just stays there on the toolbar.
Any ideas?
Thanks...

I've tried your code and it didn't show in the main toolbar. Just under the Reports category as expected. Are you sure you've didn't mark it as a favourite ? How about unpublishing everything cleanly and then republishing ? Those toolbar buttons can get sticky sometimes specially involving Actions or Workflows in the project.

Is there a Workflow extension implemented on the graph?

Rick:  I've had it happen before, but I can usually fix it by restarting the application or doing an IISReset.   This time nothing seems to work...
BOmosura:  No - no Workflow...

Apparently, this is an issue in my particular Acumatica instance - cause unknown - as I published in a client's instance and the button did NOT show up on the toolbar.
